# Getting syntax error for when using ':' to specify types

Tags: typescript

So I'm a beginner learning typescript. I have some code like:

```
let num: number = 123;
console.log(123);
```

And when I use Node.js to run this file, which is saved as `test.ts`. I get `SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':'`.

As far as I understand, this *is* how we set the type of a variable in TS right? I'm using VSCode by the way, I have node and npm installed. I also have typescript installed. I verified by checking their versions. I can't find anything online for this problem because it's just so silly.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: NodeJS does not run TypeScript. I don't know where you got the tutorial, but TypeScript needs to be compiled to JavaScript. There's no engine that runs TypeScript directly. The maximum that you can find are different modules or engines that compile TypeScript on-the-fly to make it feel that is running TypeScript directly (like Deno), but is still compiling it in memory. Also, as a side note: TypeScript has type inference. You can remove the `:number` and it will still understand that `num` is a number, as it infers the type from the assignment.

Comment: Strange. Actually, I assumed that if I could run `node test.js` then I could run `node test.ts`. I guess I was wrong. My mistake was that I wrote JS code in TS then ran it as .TS but node in this case was actually running JS. Thank you for the clarification

Comment: I guess someone can close this question, I don't know how to.

Comment: [use the `tsx` package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tsx)

it runs all typescript in node from ES3 to ESNext/NodeNext

it's the superior alternative to tsnode

you simply run `yarn tsx script.ts` or whatever your target path is

if  using npm it's `npx tsx <path to file>`

Comment: I added my comment as an answer. Is better to not delete it just in case someone has the same problem, can find the answer here. PS: The `tsx` package is an example of the compilers that simulate running TypeScript on-the-fly I was talking about, yep.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NodeJS does not run TypeScript. TypeScript needs to be compiled to JavaScript. There's no engine that runs TypeScript directly. The maximum that you can find are different modules or engines that compile TypeScript on-the-fly to make it feel that is running TypeScript directly (like Deno), but is still compiling it in memory.

*Side note*: TypeScript has type inference. You can remove the `:number` and it will still understand that num is a `number`, as it infers the type from the assignment.